# Karate match two json files(expected json and API response) irrespective of the order of array elements

Tags: karate, functional-testing

Expected Response:

```
{"data":{
{"assignments":[{"locationId":"1186755","locationName":"X.11.11"},{"locationId":"1186756","locationName":"X.11.12"}]}}}
```

Response:

```
{"data":{
{"assignments":[{"locationId":"1186756","locationName":"X.11.12"},{"locationId":"1186755","locationName":"X.11.11"}]}}}
```

I saw a SO post stating to use karate.sort(response, x=>x.locationId), when i tried it's giving me empty response. Is there any simple way i can achieve do the comparison of whole response file irrespective of order?

Note: I even tried contains only, but it's failing the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `contains deep`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64373344/143475

```
* def response = {"assignments":[{"locationId":"1186755","locationName":"X.11.11"},{"locationId":"1186756","locationName":"X.11.12"}]}}}
* match response contains deep {"assignments":[{"locationId":"1186756","locationName":"X.11.12"},{"locationId":"1186755","locationName":"X.11.11"}]}}}
```

Comment: I tried this ,so deep is matching even if one array element is not present - `* def response = {"assignments":[{"locationId":"1186755","locationName":"X.11.11"},{"locationId":"1186756","locationName":"X.11.12"}]}}}`                                                                                
 `* match response contains deep {"assignments":[{"locationId":"1186756","locationName":"X.11.12"},{"locationId":"1186756","locationName":"X.11.12"}]}}}`

Comment: @harshinireddy yes. now please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72435914/143475